# What will happen if I transfer the registration of the primary domain on my 1and1.com account?

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registrar

I have a hosting account with 1and1.com, and several domain registered and hosted with them.  I need to transfer the registration of the **primary domain** on my account to a new registrar, but I don't really want to move all of my domains with them.  Will transferring only the primary domain have any adverse effect on the other domains hosted on that account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using vanity nameservers for your other domains, you'll need to ensure that your glue records come over with the transfer (I've had these lost in transit before), but apart from that there should be no discernable difference.

Comment: By vanity nameservers, do you mean (for instance) ns1.myprimarydomain.com, etc.?  I.e. using those nameservers for my other domains on the account?  In that case, I should be fine - I'm just using the default nameservers on all of them.

Comment: @tnorth - correct, vanity name servers are nameservers that use your primary domain (hence they actually loop back on themselves). If you're not using them, then go for it.